# how to Split output and print only a part of output in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written a code to find the number of mails from Gmail inbox.The below code prints 1-100 of 5198.I want the output as only 5198.Can anyone pls help how to get a part of the text as output from a webelement.?

```
package com.training.edureka.selenium.module4;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class numberOfMails {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='email']"));
    email.sendKeys("ukn@gmail.com");
    WebElement next1 = driver.findElement(By.className("CwaK9"));
    next1.click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"));
    pwd.sendKeys("juiweji123*");
    WebElement next2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='RveJvd snByac']"));
    next2.click();
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    String inbox = driver.findElement(By.id(":ya")).getText();
    System.out.println(inbox);




}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the text by `of`

```
String inbox = driver.findElement(By.id(":ya")).getText();
String[] data = inbox.split("of ");
System.out.println(data[1]);
```